# How to check for NaN values when accessing a multi index?

Tags: python, multi-index

I am using the condition below to check for NaN values when accessing a series in a multi index and this series contains NaN value but for some reason, when this condition is tested, it is not recognizing these NaN values and still executes the code. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
if df['A'].loc[:, 'B'][C]['D'] is not None:
```

Answer (score 0):

Import numpy and then use the method isnan on your condition:

```
numpy.isnan(df['A'].loc[:, 'B'][C]['D'])
```

In case you need a reference:
[numpy.isnan()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Comment: this part is working but i still don't understand why it is still running the code after when the whole series is NaN. is it possible for it to be stored as string instead?